# What is the contour of a graph

Tags: graph-theory

I am reading the paper "A Linear-time Algorithm for Drawing
a Planar Graph on a Grid" and it says:

let w<sub>1</sub>  , ..., w<sub>m</sub> be the contour of G<sub>k-1</sub>

where G<sub>k-1</sub> seems to be either a graph, or the embedding of a graph. What does the "contour" of graph mean? I am trying to search for "contour graph" and I am only getting the geographic meaning.

Comment: My guess is the contour of a planar graph is the boundary of the (unique) polygon of infinite area. The paper is behind a paywall, but are the $w_i$ edges?

Comment: [Here is a non paywall version.](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002001909500020D) 
Your answer makes sense within the context. I've heard the term outerplanar or outerplanarity of the graph. Are those commonly used to mean the same thing as contour does here?

Comment: I don’t know. I occasionally teach Graph Theory, but it’s not my research area.

Answer (score 2):

The geographical idea can be extended for graphs.

Most generally, a contour is a set of points that share a common measure.

The most obvious definition in your case would be the set of points that are a certain number of steps away from a perhaps arbitrarily chosen central point.

At the start of the algorithm, the contour (distance 0) would be the first chosen point.

At the end of the first iteration, the contour would be the set of vertices that are distance 1 from the first chosen point. I'm guessing that $G_{k-1}$ would be the subgraph created from the vertices that are distance 1 or less away from the first chosen point.